# rails to_json always with double quote, how can i delete them?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, function

say i have a hash like this {"onDoubleClick"=>"function(e){alert(e.message);}"}
how can i get the function instead of string when i get the json on the client.

like this:

**{"onDoubleClick":function(e){alert(e.message);}}**

i tried put the # at the beginning but not work.{"onDoubleClick"=>"#function(e){alert(e.message);}"}

anybody encounter this problem before?
thanks

Comment: `{"onDoubleClick":function(e){alert(e.message);}}` is not valid JSON, so serializing to JSON is the wrong thing to do.  It looks like you want to serialize to JavaScript instead.

Comment: JSON is a data transport format, if you want JavaScript, the use JavaScript. If you remove the quotes, then you aren't generating JSON. You almost certainly should have a serious refactor so that the functions are stored in a static JavaScript file and included in the page at load time - and then pass pure data to the client, and use that data to decide which function to call.

Comment: thanks David, that's reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you should output it as a literal function from the server instead of a string. That would save you the parse-as-string and then eval() on the client.

If it's not possible to output the literal function, you can call eval() on it to turn it into a function. If a variable named o stores the result of the JSON, you can run:

```
o["onDoubleClick"] = eval(o["onDoubleClick"]);
```

to evaluate the string into a function and store it back in the same variable.

Comment: well,it seems not so elegant as i want. i thought it will be a option of method to_json to eliminate the quotes.

Comment: IE 6, does strange things with `eval` when the string body is a function definition.  It will return `undefined` for this.  A workaround is to `eval('0,' + o.onDoubleClick)` instead.  This makes the top level expression a comma expression which IE handles correctly.

Comment: i am doing this because i am using jqgrid on the server, and i am going to concat the "onDoubleClick:function()...." instead of just to_json , the json problem eval problem would be ok. am i right?

Answer (score 1):

To get around this problem, I created an object to hold "unquoted" Javascript items such as function outputs, and then added a "to_javascript" to Hash that uses the unquoted version on objects that make it available.

For example, this works for me:
    options[:controls] = {
      :bold => {:visible => true},
      :italic => {:visible => true},
      :underline => {:visible => true},
      :insertUnorderedList => {:visible => true},
      :lol => {
        :visible => true,
        :exec => JavascriptUnquoted.new("function() { $('##{html_id}').wysiwyg('insertImage', '/images/lol_emoticon.jpg'); }")
      }

options.to_javascript ==> { "controls":{"italic":{"visible":true},"underline":{"visible":true},"insertUnorderedList":{"visible":true},"lol":{"visible":true,"exec":function() { $('#review_text').wysiwyg('insertImage', '/images/lol_emoticon.jpg'); } } }

https://gist.github.com/771749

Comment: thanks. finally i used custom to_json method,i put some special charater in the string such as "--#function(){....}#--", and escape the /"--# staff.

Comment: After I spent more time reading about jQuery and staring at my code, I realized that in most cases it is a better pattern to have a custom Javascript file or jQuery extension that gets initialized with the server-side values.  You could still use the above method for the initialization, but at some point you are writing Javascript in Ruby, which feels really inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use eval():

```
var key = "OnDoubleClick";
var value = "function(e){alert(e.message);}";
eval("var " + key + "=" + value);
```

Comment: There is no need to `eval` to introduce variables, and this will not be compatible with ES5 strict mode, so if you have to `eval`, I would use Zach's approach instead.